# ASP.NET Webpage with link to Confluence Wiki using Windows login credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I've been tasked with seeing if we can give users of our internal web application help links to documentation pages on our company's Confluence Wiki. But here's the problem, the requirement is that users should not have to log into Confluence because otherwise they won't bother using the help links (which is understandable). Is there a way to forward a user to Confluence and log them in with their current windows AD credentials? Every example of their api involves you supplying a username and password. We can't have that. If they are logged into our web app with their network cred, they should be able to see a page on our Confluence Wiki w/o logging in again.

Is this possible/practical or should we just use our own help docs system?

Note - when I log into our Confluence Wiki I use my Win AD credentials, so the two systems are connected. I just have no clue how to send a user and their credentials to their system from my asp.net webpage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to configure your Confluence server to accept NTLM Authentication.  I can't find the specific directions for Confluence, but given it shares backend code with Team City, you might find these directions helpful: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NTLM+HTTP+Authentication

At the very least hopefully this helps you find what to Google next.

By the way, You don't want to setup your website to forward credentials.  It is possible, but your scenario is a simple website redirect.  Credential forwarding would be if your are trying to talk to the server as an application server (and even then generally to be avoided).